# How to draw MKOverlays one by one?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

I am using MKMapView MKPolyline to draw overlays on map. Suppose i have 4 points (a,b,c,d).
I am trying to show overlay between a-b,b-c,c-d. I am trying to show these overlays step by step,that means i want to show first a-b overlay then b-c overlay and in last c-d overlay. But these all overlays are drawn in single shot. How would i prevent this so that i can show these overlays one by one?

**Edit:**

Another functionality i am going to add in it: I have added two buttons "**Start**" and "**Pause**". When i click on start button it start plotting, and when i click on pause button it should be pause at some point where we clicked pause button. Can we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is in your view controller, implement the `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol, which gives you callbacks when your overlays have been added.  You can implement a method that just draws one line segment (two points), and trigger that method each time you're notified that another line overlay has been added.

Declare some instance variables in your view controller:

```objc
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate> {
@private
    MKMapView* mapView;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates[4];
    int lineNumber;
    BOOL isPaused;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
```

Then in your view controller .m file:

```objc
- (void)addNextLine {    
    if (!isPaused) {  
    // move to the next line
        lineNumber++;

        MKPolyline* line = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates: &coordinates[lineNumber - 1]
                                                     count: 2];
        [self.mapView addOverlay: line];
    }
}

- (void)drawPolylines {
    isPaused = NO;

    // initialize the list of coordinates for the line segments
    coordinates[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(47.8, -122.0);
    coordinates[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(47.9, -122.0);
    coordinates[2] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(47.9, -122.1);
    coordinates[3] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(48.0, -122.1);
    lineNumber = 0;

    self.mapView.region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(coordinates[0], MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.2, 0.2));

    // start adding lines one at a time
    [self addNextLine];
}

// MKMapViewDelegate callback when an overlay has been added
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMap didAddOverlayViews:(NSArray *)overlayViews {
    if (lineNumber < 3) {
        // schedule the next line segment to be drawn after a 2 second delay:
        [self performSelector: @selector(addNextLine) withObject:nil afterDelay: 2.0f];
    }
}

// MKMapViewDelegate callback when an overlay's view needs to be generated
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id < MKOverlay >)overlay {
    if ([[overlay class] isSubclassOfClass: [MKPolyline class]]) {
        MKPolylineView* view = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline: overlay];
        view.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
        view.lineWidth = 2;
        view.fillColor = [UIColor redColor];
        return view;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

You can trigger the whole process to start by calling:

```objc
[self drawPolylines];
```

In my code, it has a 2 second delay between each line being added.  Remove/change that if you like.

---

**Edit:** In order to start and pause the process with buttons, connect your `UIButton`s to these actions:

```objc
-(IBAction)onStart: (id)sender {
    if (isPaused) {
        isPaused = NO;
        [self addNextLine];
    } else {
        [self drawPolylines];
    }
}

-(IBAction)onPause: (id)sender {
    isPaused = YES;
}
```